# How would I be able to import ES6 React Component from a package in node_modules?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, ecmascript-6, create-react-app

So I have this problem where I have created a project using `create-react-app`. I have another project `common-components` which has webpack and a build process and has all the common and shareable components. what I did was I `npm link` `common-components` and then `npm link common-components` inside the Main project to make it avaible as node module. now the problem is when I try importing the ES6 React components It gives a transpile error. and I know this why it throws that. It doesnt transpiled by the `babel-loader` I am using in the Main project. I tried `include` this in the entry. But It still doesnt transpiled which It should. I donnot wanna build it to `es5` and then import. I wanted to import it as it is and then build it with the Main project.

webpack: `include : ['/mainPath', "/sharecomponentpath"]`

Comment: Did you figure it out?

Comment: No, This is not possible. Your node_modules will work only if they are ES5 compiled. So if you wanna share code, Make it a module and publish it on npm.

Other solution will be using  Lerna `https://github.com/lerna/lerna`

Comment: Hi, I figured it out, and it works by the way.. I managed to do it with react-scripts v2.1.5 and react-app-rewired + customize-cra. overriding the webpack config to include the sharedcomponentpath like @Fida said. Not that it **doesn't work with symlinks**, it has to compile the original source files. So you can add something like fs.realpathSync("/sharedcomponentpath") to the webpack include.. to make it work.

Comment: Wrote a blog post about this issue: https://medium.com/capriza-engineering/sharing-source-code-and-libraries-in-react-bd30926df312